# If I want to create new taxonomies (e.g. Project / Documents / Etc...) is it better to create them in the theme's functions.php or within a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, theme-development

I'm trying to create new taxonomies. What is the best practice? Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think it depends on the case. If the taxonomy is essential part of the theme, then functions.php might be appropriate place for registering it. If the taxonomy doesn't care which theme is in use on the site, then a custom plugin might be better place for it.

Please note that asking about best practices isn't quite on topic here as they can get rather opinion-based.

From meta: [How should I ask for best practices (or should I not ask)?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4644/how-should-i-ask-for-best-practices-or-should-i-not-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll keep best practice to myself.